# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr? in latex

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow, multicolumn

I get the error mentioned in the title of the question. Can you help me please ?

```
    \begin{table}[htb!]
      \centering
        \caption{\textit{Résultats global}} \label{tableau4}
        \resizebox{0.5\columnwidth}{!}{%            
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    Scénario & \multirow{2}{*}{Type d'instance} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{MIP-5.1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{MIP-5.2}\\
                                \cline{3-6}
                                                & Objectif & Nombre districts & Objectif & Nombre districts  \\
                                        \hline
                                                & \multirow{2}{*}{1} &R &50 & & & \\
                                                \cline{2-6}
                                                &C &14 & & & \\
                                        \hline
                                                & \multirow{2}{*}{2} &R &50 &10 & & \\
                                                \cline{2-6}
                                                &C &30 & & & \\
                                        \hline
                                                & \multirow{2}{*}{3} &R &39 &6 & & \\
                                                \cline{2-6}
                                                &C &50 &7 & & \\
                                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}%
            }
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please complete your code so that it produces the error you get when we copy-paste-try-to-compile it. However, you have tried to use 7 columns but only defined 6. Hence the error.

Comment: Mmm… Comment aside:  shouldn't the « Résultats » be « globaux »?

Comment: « Résultats » without "s". By the way, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several misplaced `&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{Résultats global}} \label{tableau4}

\resizebox{0.5\columnwidth}{!}{%            
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Scénario &
    \multirow{2}{*}{Type d'instance} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{MIP-5.1} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{MIP-5.2}\\
  \cline{3-6}
         & & Objectif & Nombre districts & Objectif & Nombre districts  \\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{1} &R &50 & & & \\
  \cline{2-6}
           &C &14 & & & \\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{2} &R &50 &10 & & \\
  \cline{2-6}
           &C &30 & & & \\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{3} &R &39 &6 & & \\
  \cline{2-6}
           &C &50 &7 & & \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Scaling tables is in general the very last thing to try.

Here's how I'd typeset it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\caption{\textit{Résultats global}} \label{tableau4}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccc@{}}
\toprule
  Scénario & Type d'instance & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MIP-5.1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MIP-5.2}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
         & & Objectif & N. districts & Objectif & N. districts  \\
\midrule
1 &R &50 & & & \\
  &C &14 & & & \\
\midrule
2 &R &50 &10 & & \\
  &C &30 & & & \\
\midrule
3 &R &39 &6 & & \\
  &C &50 &7 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd load `caption` for a correct spacing between caption and table…

Comment: @Bernard That's an option, of course.